# Display lowest paid salary, name, and id for EACH department in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Homework Question:

Display Last Name, Department id, and lowest salary of the employee of the person in that department

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT department_id, min(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id;
```

This works but my teacher wants us to use sub queries and I can't understand how to do that.

Comment: use correlated query..... where the inner query takes input from the outer query

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `not exists`:

```
select last_name, department_id, salary
from employees e1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from employees e2 
    where e1.department_id = e2.department_id
    and e1.salary > e2.salary
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is use your initial query as subquery to join with :)

```
select last_name, department_id, X.salary
from employees e1
join (SELECT department_id, min(salary) as salary
      FROM employees
      GROUP BY department_id;) X
on e1.department_id = X.department_id;
```

Hope it helps.